# How to use dynamic row ui-component for frontend magento2?

Tags: frontend, uicomponent

How to use dynamic row ui-component for frontend magento2 ?

Comment: Do you need it on admin side??

Comment: @GeeEmm No, I need implement it on front-end.

Comment: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/402bQ

Comment: @DasharathPatel have you find a solution to add a dynamic row component for frontend?